# is it normal that react native's ScrollView scrollTo method can triggle the onScroll function?

Tags: react-native

```js
const handleCurrent = (index: number) => {
    scrollRef.current.scrollTo({ x: 0, y: index * 202, animated: true });
};

const handleOnScroll = () => {
  console.log("scrolling");
}

<Pressable onPress={() => handleCurrent(2)}>a button</Pressable>
<ScrollView
 ref={scrollRef}
 onScroll={handleOnScroll} />
.......
</ScrollView>
```

is there any way I can know if the scrollView scrolling triggered by hands or by the code(like the scrollTo method)?

I have some extra works to do in `handleOnScroll` function, but I don't want execute the `handleOnScroll` function when I use scrollTo method.

Answer (score 1):

`onScroll` will always be called when the component is scrolled, whether manually or programmatically. If you want to fire a callback only when the component is scrolled manually, you can use `onScrollBeginDrag` or `onScrollEndDrag` (docs [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview)).

It doesn't look to me like there's a built-in way to react only to a programmatic scroll, but since you're doing the triggering, you can perform whatever action you like when you call `scrollTo`.

Comment: but `onScrollEndDrag` function has a big problem, it only trace the moment that I lose my hand, but in reality, ScrollVIew will continue keep scrolling for a while, which makes the final result is incorrect.

Comment: Try https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#onmomentumscrollend

Comment: I test it on IOS, I found the `onMomentumScrollEnd` won't be triggered when I slowly scrolling manually, android works fine

Comment: Have you checked their github for issues related to yours?

Comment: I don't see any issues related to mine, but I created a issue, https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/39189